# Regarding Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

My question is  that :-
In interview interviewer asked me:
In servlet there is a method which has 10 params. and the request is send to other controller or servlet. in other servlet we need only 6 params. what we have to do?

I answered: you can get params with the help of `req.getParameters(1,2,3,4,5,..);`
OR
for each element i can write `req.getParameter(1);req.getParameter(2);...... (6);`
OR
we can set all required values in **session** scope
but the interviewer was not satisfied with my answer...

Please tell me what is the best answer for the same.

**Thanks in Advance :)**

Comment: I guess he wanted to hear which *pattern* you will going to follow rather than a specific implementation.

Comment: See for example: http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the interviewer wanted to hear you talk about the adapter pattern, and not what specific code you were going to write.

From your comment, it sounds like you have not heard of patterns before. They are common designs or approaches to a particular problem, and they make it easier to 1) spot a particular problem which has a common solution and 2) to describe to other developers the design or approach.

The adapter pattern translates one interface (the method with 10 parameters) into a different interface (another method with 6 parameters)

In this case, the code solution might involve req.getParameter but the interviewer wanted to see that you could identify this situation as one where you would use the adapter pattern.

Comment: This is a *very* brief introduction to patterns and a *very* brief description of the adapter pattern.. There is a lot on in the internet about them